# Circumventing recruiter when client known beforehand

Tags: recruitment, contracting

I'm in contact with a recruiter for an contract opportunity at Company A, and we have a interview with his client scheduled. This is my first time working with this recruiter, but it has been a positive experience.

Meanwhile, a different contract came up, where an employee of Company B posted in a group on Facebook that they are on the look-out for contractors, and to just PM them directly. It's a project I might be interested in, although I haven't messaged them just yet.

Shortly after, I get an email from the previous recruiter, asking if I he can submit my CV to Company B for this project.

Now, normally when I'm dealing with multiple recruiters pitching the same opportunity, I go for first-come-first-serve, but this approach doesn't work here.

Technically, I haven't been in contact with Company B yet, but it was my intention to at least PM and ask for more details. On the other hand, I don't like circumventing the recruiter, it feels like a no-no move (I would not have done it, if I had read the emails first). I'd like to of course keep good relationship with the recruiter.

What's the up- and downsides for either approach on my end?

I feel, though I might be wrong, that Company B would prefer to take a contractor that applies directly, as they then won't have to pay a cut to the recruitment agency.

Comment: did you sign a contract with the recruiter?

Comment: @mhoran_psprep Nope. He contacted me about Opportunity A, I haven't talked to him about Opportunity B.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can just tell him no thanks, I already know of this opportunity through my personal network. No need to be sorry, it's just fair that way - the recruiter did not add value on this opportunity.

This will save the company costs in the event they contract you, which is obviously always a plus for you.

The downside could be, if the recruiter has a good relationship to that particular company, he may be able to present you better. I doubt that in this case, as the company already asked to be PM-ed directly. If you feel he has better access or will greatly simplify the process for you, you can go for it.

Remember, in your case the recruiter is  probably paid a fee by the hiring company so he does not work for you, he works for the company. He does not really care who gets the job, as long as it is one of his introductions. You owe him nothing, you are raw material for him to generate income from.

Comment: "He does not really care who get´s the job, as long as it is one of his introductions. You owe him nothing, **you are raw material for him to generate income**." This is *the* line. Think of recruiters like this always and you will never be led astray.